# Sort a Hazelcast IList using comparator

Tags: java, list, sorting, hazelcast

I am trying to sort a list (`IList`) in hazelcast. I have searched and not able to find a way to do it.

Please give some pointers on how can I sort it.
Please note that below is not complete and working code just a part of it

```
IList hlist = hazelCastClient.getList("test") // hazelcastClient has been created already
hlist.add(message1)
hlist.add(message2)
hlist.add(message3)
Comparator comparator = new SomeComparator()
```

How can I sort this hazelcast List using the compare function overridden in comparator. Is there some other way to sort a hazelcast collection?

Answer (score 0):

Does hazelCastClient.getList return a java.util.List? Then you can use the sort function - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: It returns an IList which extends List. I have tried 2 ways:  hlist.sort(comparator)              - This one fails
Collections.sort(hlist,comparator)    - This one returns the result but that is not sorted according to comparator definition

Comment: I am not sure why your comparator is not working. Just read this about predicates, this could do sorting too I guess - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968146/have-hazelcast-predicate-return-sorted-collection